# hide status bar on ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

This is not a duplicate question as far as I can tell.
I have no problem hiding the status bar on iphone but I cannot figure out how to do it with an ipad.
I have followed as many examples as I can find to try to hide it but nothing works. I currently have the appropriate stuff set in plist and it works fine for iphone but the same code does not work for ipad.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Please post what you have tried, with code and which iOS version you are targeting.

Comment: What does this have to do with the `xcode IDE`??? Also this sounds like a duplicated question, sounds very much like every other question how to hide the status bar on `iOS` devices.

Comment: Check your ~iPad xibs. Click on the main view and check the properties tab to see if status bar is 'none'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide status bar in iOS 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826320/how-to-hide-status-bar-in-ios-7) and [How to hide status bar in iOS 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20152738/ios6-hidden-status-bar)

Comment: As I wrote quite clearly in the question. I have tried EVERYTHING I have found on this issue in and it does not resolve the issue. I am targeting for 7.1 and using xcode 5.1.  If you do not know the answer or choose not to respond that's fine, but please don't be a dick. Thanks

Comment: It can help if you list the examples that didn't work for you so they are not flagged as duplicates.

Comment: I have tried this 
UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance = NO, this UIStatusBarHidden = YES and this

Comment: Dear Mr Popeye, perhaps you can clarify. I assume it has to with xcode IDE because that's what I'm using to write and test the code. Am I mistaken.  As I will state a third time, it is not a duplicate question, it is an extended question.  It may sound like every other question, but if you read a little further you'll see that I am asking beyond a duplicate question.  Do you have the answer?  If so, please let me know and I'll be grateful.

Comment: I also tried this [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade]; and this [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;
and this - (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the keys:

[UIStatusBarHidden](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) = YES

and

[UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/AppearanceCustomization.html) = NO

into the [info.plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html) file?

Comment: I have Status bar is initially hidden = YES and View controller-based status bar appearance = NO.  I do not see the option to set up the two that you mention that start with UI

Comment: Open your info.plist file in Xcode, right click on the table and enable "Show Raw Keys/Values". Now you should be able to see the raw key name, this should equal the ones I mentioned in the answer. Also check that you do not reenable the status bar in your XIB/storyboard  or programmatically!

Comment: Ok. I did that. Everything checks out, still shows status bar with ipad.

Comment: I think I'm getting closer.  The status bar shows up when I run an iphone app on an ipad or in the simulator.  It does not show up when I set it xcode to be a universal app.  The problem with a universal setting is (I think) I have to have separate storyboard for ipad. Is this true?  I just want to have the app set as iphone using one storyboard and not see the status bar on either the ipad or iphone. Everything else seems to work fine with an app set to iphone running on ipad or the ipad simulator except the status bar shows up on the ipad.  Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Actually I would suggest that you use separate storyboards, but for what it is worse you can use the iphone storyboard also for an ipad, but not vice versa. Just go to your info.plist and set for example Main_iPhone also as value for UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad

Comment: Yes, I think you have to set the app as universal and use two storyboards. There ought to be a better way, and I think it worked prior to 7.1 but i have not found a better way to do it.